# Self-closing xsl:template tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking at an old xsl file and trying to understand the why the original author has defined a number of `<xsl:template>` elements as *self closing tags* containing a  `match` attribute. In the example below my question would be in regards to `<xsl:template match="title" />`:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
          <body>
              <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
              <xsl:apply-templates/>  
          </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title" />

    <xsl:template match="artist">
        Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since the tags are self-closing, there is obviously no content in the `<xsl:template \>`. What's the point of doing this? Is this a technique to "hide" the XML data that associated to the `template` via the match attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self closing `xsl:template` tags serve to suppress the matched node.  This is commonly used in conjunction with the identity transformation so that everything else is copied to output *except* the suppressed nodes.

`<xsl:template match="title" />`, for example, would do nothing for `title` elements matched in the input document.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense in that stylesheet that explicitly uses `<xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>` to then also use `<xsl:template match="title" />` to make sure `title` elements produce no output but in case of e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>` or simply `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the template of the `cd` parent you could then use the empty `<xsl:template match="title" />` to make sure `title` elements don't produce any output.

In the given stylesheet it would of course be easier to simply remove the `<xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>`.

Where it is often used is together with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to which you then add some templates to transform certain elements and you can add empty templates (e.g. `<xsl:template match="title" />`) to remove other elements (e.g. `title` elements) as that way they don't produce any output.